# Why is my entire es6 class importing instead of instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, ecmascript-6

I have an es6 class "GetLink" in the chrome plugin I am building. This class will get the first link for the active tab when called with chrome's "tabs" api. Here is the code:

```
export class GetLink {
    constructor(tabs) {
        this.ajaxGet(
            `${tabs[0].url}?debug`,
            data => this.getLink(data),
            error => {throw new Error(`AJAX GET failed because response was ${error}`)}
        );
    }

    ajaxGet(url, success, error) {
        if(!window.XMLHttpRequest) throw new Error(`This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest`);
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(request.readyState === 4) {
                if(request.status !== 200) {
                    console.log(request.status);
                    if(error && typeof error === "function") {
                        error(error);
                    }
                }
                if(success && typeof success === "function") {
                    success(request.responseText);
                }
            }
        };
        request.open("GET", url);
        request.send();
    }

    getLink(data) {
        let nodeList = document.createElement("html");
        nodeList.innerHTML = data;
        return nodeList.querySelector("a").href;
    }
}

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, tabs => {
    console.log(new GetLink(tabs));
});
```

I'd expect, using the "new" keyword that I would get the result of the GetLink instance. Instead I get the entire, uninstantiated class.

if in "getAjax" success handler call in the constructor I log "this.getLink(data)" rather than return it I get the log by calling new GetLink(tabs).

Is this because getAjax is async? If so what is a good pattern to solve this problem? (I tried returning this.getAjax in the constructor, assigning the instance to a variable, etc) If not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: "*Instead I get the entire, uninstantiated class.*" - why do you think so? What exactly do you see, maybe post a screenshot? "*I would get the result of the GetLink instance.*" - an instance has no "result", it's just that, an object - with no properties in your case. So what do you refer to, the result of the ajax call?

Comment: It looks like you *really* should not use a `class`. Try to get it working with plain functions, and show us that code.

Comment: I am still using a class, but I did get it working. The issues was that I was not doing async well. I made the async methods return promises, and removed the constructor (making it an empty function), now I can access all of the methods with import hydraLinkGenerator and chain them in the appropriate order. If you are interested the code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/pbn6rn0v/1/